# Spring Framework SAML unable to find needed beans through autowired

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am trying to setup SSO with spring security SAML (spring security 4.0.1 and saml 1.0.1) but on startup I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLLogger] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:616)
    ... 91 more
```

Here is my context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">

...

    <security:http pattern="/saml/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_RUN')" />
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http> 
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="!@#$torch" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider  ref="samlAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:saml/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="torch1234"/>
        <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="torchlms" value="torch1234"/>
        </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="torchlms"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetailsServiceImpl" />
        <property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="samlUserDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.prometheus.torchlms.security.saml.SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="authorizationService" />
        <constructor-arg ref="principalHolderService" />
    </bean>
...
```

The error makes me think it is missing the component scan, but I added that. The only thing I can think of is its something wrong with the way I defined my context namespace, but that looks right to me too. Thoughts?

Comment: did you try to add the SAMLDefaultLogger to your XML?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up adding a bunch of other beans as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret to figure all this stuff out is to look at the sample apps context files and paste in everything, then remove the stuff you don't need. There is a ton of stuff in the sample app that isn't mentioned in the docs. I was able to get it working with that approach.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach - start with the sample application, and eventually remove configuration you don't want. At some point I'll add namespace/Java configuration helpers to Spring SAML which will hide this, but there's not much time to get this done...

Comment: Where can i get the sample app?

Comment: @Swaprks https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml